# ListView row layout height not being set

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want my rows to be 50dp high, but for some reason it will only `wrap_content`.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/master_selector" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:contentDescription="Category" >
    </ImageView>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textColor="#ebebeb"
        android:textSize="25sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I cannot figure out WHY the 50dp is having no effect?  It's on a regular ListView

Edit:  Screenshot:

As you see, the rows are close together.  The text is only 25sp (on regular text size).

[image]

Edit:  Changing `TextView` height to `50dp` and `gravity` to `center_vertical` fixes it.

Comment: can u post a screen shot?

Comment: could you test without background image?

Comment: @Raghunandan  Screen shot added

Comment: Does your XML have an error? It seems in the TextView in `android:text` you are referencing the TextView element itself.

Comment: set the background of the textView to red , and the background of the LinearLayout to green , to see the differences in size ,

Comment: Can you try setting the row height to 50dp inside of the getView method of your custom adapter ?

Comment: @NickolaiAstashonok The background is only a press state.  The dark wallpaper you see if on the `FrameLayout` underneath.

Comment: @Houcine Basically, the rows are based on the height of whatever is taller, the `TextView` or `ImageView`

Comment: The answer below by @Graeme fixes the issue, but is that a workaround?

Comment: @Terry  Good catch, but fixing that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout values of an inflated view can be easily forgotten in some implementations (Usually because they're added with a specified LayoutParam object as is the case in `ListView`).

You can fix this by adding one of the childrens heights to be 50dp which will correctly display.

Comment: Well, this works, but it seems like a workaround?  I set `TextView` to 50dp and `gravity` to `center_vertical`

Comment: That's why I do :) If there is something I'm missing I'd be interested to know to - but from my investigation that's what I found.

Comment: Going with this, it works for me.  Just wish I knew why it ignored the layout height.